# chunking soap web service using axis2 in java?

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, chunks

I am implementing invoking of a soap web service in java
I have a wsdl file that I have imported using the embedded wsdl2java in axis2
then I was able to call the web service and it is working fine
util the size of the request exceed a 30 mega in size
the output request consist of the following parameters:

```
<param1>some value</param1>
<array>
   recored1
   recored2
   .
   .
   .
</array>
```

I was able to send 500000 recodes but when exceed this number I stuck in getting "java heap space error"
question is  is there any way to send the soap request in small chunks ...and does importing the WSDL using xmlbeans affect the performance
for rest APIs I was able to add transfer encoding for chunk and provide the body of it in small chunks but for soap services I found no solutions, please if there is any example of that I will be grateful.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Streaming one transaction require all pipeline involved steps are in a streaming fashion. If one of them collapse the stream (i.e. `myStream.collect(toList())`) then, the streaming process will be broken and, at that point, all the input stream will be into memory (maybe filtered, reducted, ...).

In general, to process a XML input in a streaming fashion (under axis2) you could use [Axiom](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/index.html), a simple example to process in streaming is ([from here](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/quickstart-samples.html#Loading_local_chunks_from_a_large_XML_document)):

```
public void processFragments(InputStream in) throws XMLStreamException {
    // Create an XMLStreamReader without building the object model
    XMLStreamReader reader =
        OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(in).getDocument().getXMLStreamReader(false);
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT &&
                reader.getName().equals(new QName("tag"))) {
            // A matching START_ELEMENT event was found. Build a corresponding OMElement.
            OMElement element = 
                OMXMLBuilderFactory.createStAXOMBuilder(reader).getDocumentElement();
            // Make sure that all events belonging to the element are consumed so
            // that the XMLStreamReader points to a well defined location (namely the
            // event immediately following the END_ELEMENT event).
            element.build();
            // Now process the element.
            processFragment(element);
        } else {
            reader.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Although you can open a HTTP stream and use this snippet, unfortunately translate it to your autogenerated client is not easy.

Create an AXIOM client is much less comfortable since you must to deal with AXIOM objects, [from the documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html#clientaxiom):

```
private static EndpointReference targetEPR = 
    new EndpointReference("http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/StockQuoteService");

public static OMElement getPricePayload(String symbol) {
    OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://axiom.service.quickstart.samples/xsd", "tns");

    OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("getPrice", omNs);
    OMElement value = fac.createOMElement("symbol", omNs);
    value.addChild(fac.createOMText(value, symbol));
    method.addChild(value);
    return method;
}

public static OMElement updatePayload(String symbol, double price) {
    OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://axiom.service.quickstart.samples/xsd", "tns");

    OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("update", omNs);

    OMElement value1 = fac.createOMElement("symbol", omNs);
    value1.addChild(fac.createOMText(value1, symbol));
    method.addChild(value1);

    OMElement value2 = fac.createOMElement("price", omNs);
    value2.addChild(fac.createOMText(value2,
                                     Double.toString(price)));
    method.addChild(value2);
    return method;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        OMElement getPricePayload = getPricePayload("WSO");
        OMElement updatePayload = updatePayload("WSO", 123.42);
        Options options = new Options();
        options.setTo(targetEPR);
        options.setTransportInProtocol(Constants.TRANSPORT_HTTP);

        ServiceClient sender = new ServiceClient();
        sender.setOptions(options);

        sender.fireAndForget(updatePayload);
        System.err.println("price updated");
        OMElement result = sender.sendReceive(getPricePayload);

        String response = result.getFirstElement().getText();
        System.err.println("Current price of WSO: " + response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then you can digest the response in a streaming fashion way:

```
result.getFirstElement().getText()
```

if your WSDL definition is complex may be suitable write an AXIOM client only for big transactions but if you can split the call will be a much better approach.

Comment: thanks dear for now I just edited the java heap size as a work around solution, your method seems to work but it need some heavy modifications I will just stick to the work around for now

Comment: @kikicoder establishing a larger heap does not solve the problem only delays it. Anyway my answer is for your _"question is is there any way to send the soap request in small chunks"_ I think is correct.

Comment: dear thank you again I agree with you I just was in rush to find a work around solution until I could implement yours